# Fantasy book series with heroes who exist to fight corrupt mages

Tags: story-identification, books

Series begins from the POV of Farm Boy Protagonist™ during some sort of "harvest festival" type scene, and after the festivities a mysterious stranger pulls him aside and offers to pass down a sword that will make him an archetypical master swordsman but he has to hunt evil mages. There are several other archetypical heroes with similarly inherited powers, all for the purpose of stopping evil mages.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  How many books were there?

Comment: Protaganist -> Protagonist (Edits must be at least 10 chars.) Can someone change that, please?

Answer (score 13):

There's not a lot to go on here, but to me it feels like it might be Lawrence Watt-Evans' [*The Annals of the Chosen*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?11673) (2006-2008).  The first book [*The Wizard Lord*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?180819) does have a young man, Breaker, passed the mantle of the Swordsman, one of the Chosen who are tasked with destroying the Wizard Lord if he turns evil (at which point he becomes a Dark Lord).  (The previous Swordsman wants to retire, so the mantle is handed off peacefully.)

Breaker finds himself wondering about things that are happening, so he goes in search of the other Chosen to consult with them.  As more of the Chosen gather it becomes more obvious that something has gone wrong with the Wizard Lord and they end up having to destroy him.

The second book [*The Ninth Talisman*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?221931) starts differently, potentially adds a new member to the Chosen, (which happens every time a Dark Lord is defeated) but still ends up in a power struggle between the Wizard Lord (who hasn't quite gone Dark) and the Chosen.  This time the conflict carries through into the third book [*The Summer Palace*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?829319).

Comment: That was my first thought, as well.